# Multi-Column Primary Key in MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, key, primary-key

I'm trying to learn how to use keys and to break the habit of necessarily having `SERIAL` type IDs for all rows in all my tables.  At the same time, I'm also doing many-to-many relationships, and so requiring unique values on either column of the tables that coordinate the relationships would hamper that.

How can I define a primary key on a table such that any given value can be repeated in any column, so long as the combination of values across all columns is never repeated exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly create composite primary keys - MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql)

Comment: Can't be a duplicate of something posted 3 years later.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha ;-)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Quoted from the [CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) page:

> A PRIMARY KEY can be a multiple-column
>   index. However, you cannot create a
>   multiple-column index using the
>   PRIMARY KEY key attribute in a column
>   specification. Doing so only marks
>   that single column as primary. You
>   must use a separate PRIMARY
>   KEY(index_col_name, ...) clause.

Something like this can be used for multi-column primary keys:

```
CREATE TABLE
    product (
        category INT NOT NULL,
        id INT NOT NULL,
        price DECIMAL,
        PRIMARY KEY(category, id)
    );
```

*From [13.1.20.6 FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)*

Comment: Shouldn't you include the price in the PK (category, id, price) of your example? He's asking for 'any column' and 'across all columns' ? ... and then add a stern comment about this being suboptimal, slow and never needed in real life?  (YES! I AM nitpicking here:-)

Comment: I agree. All columns should be there

Comment: Doesn't work at all in my case. For example, if I use different category, but the same id, still show me the duplicated key.

Comment: @bagusflyer A case that I have ran into is type conversion by MySQL caused two originally different data to become the same inserted value, caising duplicated key, e.g. by casting string to number or by limiting character count.  The error message should show the exact key value after conversion, which can be used to check whether conversion happened.

Answer (score 33):

Primary key is a domain concept that uniquely (necessarily and sufficiently) identifies your entity among similar entities. A composite (multiple-column) primary key makes sense only when a part of the key refers to a particular instance of another domain entity.

Let's say you have a personal collection of books. As long as you are alone, you can count them and assign each a number. The number is the primary key of the domain of your library.

Now you want to merge your library with that of your neighbor but still be able to distinguish to whom a book belongs. The domain is now broader and the primary key is now (owner, book_id).

Thus, making each primary key composite should not be your strategy, but rather you should use it when required.

Now some facts about MySQL. If you define a composite primary key and want the RDBSM to autoincrement the ids for you, you should know about the difference between MyISAM and InnoDB behavior.

Let's say we want a table with two fields: parent_id, child_id. And we want the child_id to be autoincremented.

MyISAM will autoincrement uniquely within records with the same parent_id and InnoDB will autoincrement uniquely within the whole table.

In MyISAM you should define the primary key as (parent_id, child_id), and in InnoDB as (child_id, parent_id), because the autoincremented field should be the leftmost constituent in the primary key in InnoDB.

Comment: This is an outstanding answer.

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is a unique value for the row. It makes no sense to include price, a value that could change. Imagine if you had to change a large range of prices, then all those primary key values would change. What a mess that would be!