# insert if id does not exist or update table if id exist query?

Tags: php, mysql

hi can you help me to make my query update if table if id exist then if not insert it?
here's my query:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$a=$_POST['no1'];   $b=$_POST['ans1'];     $c=$_POST['det1'];
$d=$_POST['no2'];   $e=$_POST['ans2'];     $f=$_POST['det2'];
$g=$_POST['no3'];   $h=$_POST['ans3'];         $i=$_POST['det3'];
$j=$_POST['no4'];   $k=$_POST['ans4'];     $l=$_POST['det4'];
$m=$_POST['no5'];   $n=$_POST['ans5'];     $o=$_POST['det5'];
$p=$_POST['no6'];   $q=$_POST['ans6'];     $r=$_POST['det6'];
$s=$_POST['no7'];   $t=$_POST['ans7'];         $u=$_POST['det7'];
$v=$_POST['no8'];   $w=$_POST['ans8'];     $x=$_POST['det8'];
$y=$_POST['no9'];   z=$_POST['ans9'];      $zz=$_POST['det9'];
$aa=$_POST['no10']; $bb=$_POST['ans10'];       $cc=$_POST['det10'];

$sql=mysql_query("insert into bfp_personnel_questions `(`id`,`question_number`,`answer`,`details`) VALUES ('$id', '$a', '$b','$c'),   ('$id','$d','$e','$f'), ('$id','$g','$h','$i'), ('$id','$j','$k','$l'), ('$id','$m','$n','$o'), ('$id','$p','$q','$r'), ('$id','$s','$t','$u'), ('$id','$v','$w','$x'), ('$id','$y','$z','$zz'), ('$id','$aa','$bb','$cc')") or die(mysql_error());`

?><script>alert("Successfully Saved.");window.location="pds_1st.php?part=11";</script><?php }
}
```

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try SQL syntax [insert on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

First off, your script screams for [prepared statements](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). You could drastically improve the speed and performance by switching (especially since you're using the obsolete `mysql` extensions).

I assume that `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` or at least a `UNIQUE` index. The simplest way to do this is to do `INSERT IGNORE`, which will try to insert your record and, if they collide, ignores the error and moves on

```
INSERT INGORE INTO table(col1, col2)
VALUES('1', '2');
```

If you want to replace the values, you can use `REPLACE` in later versions of MySQL

```
REPLACE INTO table(col1, col2)
VALUES('1', '2');
```

If the key already exists, the row is updated.