# Fast way to Increment a column if another column exists?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a database table with two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Main(Id TEXT, Count INTEGER)
```

I'm currently using something like bellow code for adding a number to a column if it already exists :

```
query = SELECT * FROM Main WHERE Id=some_word LIMIT 1

if(query has some elements){
     UPDATE Main SET Count=query.count+word_count WHERE Id=some_word
}
else{
     INSERT INTO table_name SELECT some_word AS Id , word_Count AS Count 
     //some more UNION SELECT ...
}
```

How can I make those statements faster ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.
For more information, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update).

Comment: Note: I did not mark it as duplicate, as the question seems slightly different and for a different Database system.