# String primary key comprised of date and auto incrementing integer

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Basically for every record I want primary key of date + incrementing integer, and the integer resets every day.

Is this possible in SQL?

**Edit:** Thanks for the responses. I would consider doing this at the application layer, but the painful part is accessing the integer part. Another solution is to calculate the `date` at the application layer, update/retrieve the integer then insert the new record. Then reset the the variable at the end of the day.

Comment: You may want to work with a form of datenum:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update;  and drop the time of day from the datenum for record increment instead.

Comment: possible? sure! good? sure not! Just use 2 columns: (auto) Identity and Date. If you create exotic beast they ill come back and bit you

Answer (score 2):

"Is this possible in SQL?"

Yes

I would suggest having 2 rows with each value (one for the Date, one for the Integer).

What you would need is the following: a trigger for insertions that adds the NOW() value to a field. Then concat the Integer to that Date.

And another trigger to reset the Integer value at the change of day (the hour you chose)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the numbers to increase monotonically then you have to implement a locking mechanism to prevent concurrent inserts. If you only have a single session inserting data then that's fine, but it's difficult with multiple sessions.

This is a very bad design pattern for concurrency, and you'd do better with a regular sequence-generated PK, a separate date column, and another column that you populate asynchronously with the number series.