# insert into mysql if not exist else update

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have in my table of mysql this cells: ebook_data and ebook_email. I want to update ebook_data if ebook_email is same, if not insert ebook_data and ebook_email.

I don't understand werry well php and mysql.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update).

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO ebook (ebook_data, ebook_email) VALUES (NOW(), '$ebook_email') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ebook_data =VALUES(NOW())";

Comment: Don't comment your code and update it to your post.

Comment: @Andrew Flag this as a duplicate