# Mysql batch insert or update, insert if id is null otherwise update

Tags: mysql

Say I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE texts
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    body TEXT
);
```

I want to update a couple of ids, and also insert some new ones. I want to insert if the id is null, and otherwise, I want to update. So I want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO OR UPDATE 
  texts (id, body)
VALUES
  (NULL, 'create new row'),
  (NULL, 'create other new row'),
  (1, 'update id 1'),
  (2, 'update id 2'),
  (3, 'update id 3');
```

If the matching id, doesn't exist, I want to ignore the update, because then the row is apperently deleted in the meantime.

Comment: I don't think you can have a single SQL statement which updates or inserts.  You'd probably be better off inserting all those whose ids are null and updating afterwards all those whose ids are not null.

Comment: What happens if you insert a row where the `id` value is not NULL _and_ it doesn't already exist in the table?  Would that also be an insert?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql Table Insert if not exist otherwise update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would actually, want to ignore if that is the case, because I think in that case, the row would have been deleted in the time since I received the id to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a statement [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO texts (id, body) VALUES(1, "body text") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
body="body text"
```

If you want to skip the ID not null not exists in the table, maybe you can try this

```
INSERT INTO
  texts (id, body)
VALUES
  (NULL, 'create new row'),
  (NULL, 'create other new row');

UPDATE texts SET
`body` = CASE 
WHEN `id` = 1 THEN 'update id 1'
WHEN `id` = 2 THEN 'update id 2'
WHEN `id` = 3 THEN 'update id 3'
ELSE `body` END

WHERE `id`=1 OR `id`=2 OR `id`=3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer has 2 things, I don't like. The ids are not incrementing normally again. It now goes from 3,4 to 8,9, to 13,14. The other thing is that, it also insert the id, if it doesn't exists. I want to ignore if there is nothing to update.

Comment: You can compose the `VALUES(1, "body text")` by a loop to get values like `($id, $value)`, `$id` can be `NULL` or the numbers as you mentioned. Would be possible?

Comment: My main problem is that it inserts if the id doesn't exists. I only want to insert if the id is null. It now also inserts if the id =3 and the id 3 doesn't exists in the table.

Comment: How about: `if(is_null($id)) { INSERT QUERY } else { SELECT ... WHERE id=$id; if (affected_rows > 0) { UPDATE QUERY}}` ?

Comment: Maybe better:   `if(is_null($id)) { INSERT GROUP } else { UPDATE GROUP}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO texts(id, body) VALUES(1, "20") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE body=20
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer has 2 things, I don't like. The ids are not incrementing normally again. It now goes from 3,4 to 8,9, to 13,14. The other thing is that, it also insert the id, if it doesn't exists. I want to ignore if there is nothing to update.

Answer (score 1):

If performing two queries is not a problem you could UPDATE and INSERT separately. First, the UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE my_table SET field1 = 
  (CASE id 
     WHEN 1 THEN 'value1'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'value2'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'value3'
  END),
  field2 = 
  (CASE id 
     WHEN 1 THEN 'value4'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'value5'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'value6'
  END)
WHERE id IN(1,2,3)
```

On the insert side

```
INSERT INTO my_table(id, field1, field2) VALUES
  (NULL, 'value7', 'value8'),
  (NULL, 'value9', 'value10'),
  (NULL, 'value11', 'value12')
;
```

That would result in something like:

```
id | field1  | field 2
-----------------------
1  | value1  | value4
2  | value2  | value5
3  | value3  | value6
4  | value7  | value8
5  | value9  | value10
6  | value11 | value12
```

**TEST IT YOURSELF**

You could try yourself this by creating the schema

```
 CREATE TABLE `my_db`.`my_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `field2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
```

And some initial data so you can check the updates

```
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`my_table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('value', 'anotherValue');
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`my_table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('moreValue', 'justAnother');
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`my_table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('moreAndMore', 'valuesEverywhere');
```

Then just perform the queries to see with your own eyes.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE INTO 
texts (id, body)
VALUES
(NULL, 'create new row'),
(NULL, 'create other new row'),
(1, 'update id 1'),
(2, 'update id 2'),
(3, 'update id 3');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer has 2 things, I don't like. The ids are not incrementing normally again. It now goes from 3,4 to 8,9, to 13,14. The other thing is that, it also insert the id, if it doesn't exists. I want to ignore if there is nothing to update.