# Simplify PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently writing sort of a game and I need to simplify the PHP part over to MySQL.

Right now to update a column I do this (in PHP):

```
$res = $db->query("
SELECT succeeded
     , failed
     , prison 
  FROM users_crime_masteries 
 WHERE uid = $uid 
   AND cid = $crimeid
");
if($status == 'succeeded') {
        if(!$res->num_rows) {
            $db->query("INSERT INTO users_crime_masteries (uid, cid, succeeded) VALUES($uid, $crimeid, 1)");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            $row = $res->fetch_object();
            $db->query("UPDATE users_crime_masteries SET succeeded = succeeded + 1 WHERE uid = $uid AND cid = $crimeid");
            return $row->succeeded += 1;
        }
    }
```

^ This is half of the function, but you get the idea.

What i'm basically trying to achieve within mySQL only, is that if there are no rows, insert a new row with `cid` and `uid` - if a row exists, update succeeded with + 1.

I've been browsing through stackoverflow and what i basically understand is that I have to use a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query.

But i've came across this comment: [MySql Table Insert if not exist otherwise update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update#comment40033499_6036718)

I do have a column named `id`, which is auto increment, and primary key. My question is, will this cause any issues?

My current MySQL version is: 5.7.24

Also, for this `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` do I have to make the `uid` and `cid` columns a key?

**More Information:**

Changed the queries to:

```
switch($status) {
        case 'succeeded' :
            $db->query("INSERT INTO users_crime_masteries (uid, cid, succeeded) VALUES($userid, $crimeid, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE succeeded = succeeded + 1");
        break;
        case 'failed' :
            $db->query("INSERT INTO users_crime_masteries (uid, cid, failed) VALUES($userid, $crimeid, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE failed = failed + 1");
        break;
        case 'prison' :
            $db->query("INSERT INTO users_crime_masteries (uid, cid, failed, prison) VALUES($userid, $crimeid, 1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY update failed = failed + 1, prison = prison + 1");
        break;
    }
```

Ran the following MySQL Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `users_crime_masteries`


ADD UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `cid` (`cid`),
```

Did a few crimes with a different `cid`, checked through phpmyadmin but there's only one row, updating the succeeded field.

Have I missed something?

Comment: No issue @Love2Code. Just update it using the id or primary key.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: I don't understand the point of the select

Comment: If you can include ADOdb, then you could use [replace()](http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:replace) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a unique key (uid, cid) to your table then `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should work. Your `id` column will not be affected or cause problems.

You should furthermore take care that your code is not prone to sql injections, it looks like it could be.

Comment: almost works! Can you check the edit i posted please?

Comment: I don't know your model exactly but I think it would rather be `ALTER TABLE users_crime_masteries ADD  UNIQUE KEY crime_key (uid, cid);`. crime_key is just the name of the key, you're free to choose another name for it.