# Insert or Update MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table

```
ID  CHIP_ID STATUS MOD_STATUS_DATE_TIME
1      123    w    2024-02-07 11:20:06
2      456    i    2024-02-07 11:21:00
```

I need insert or update this table in the following way:

1. If we have no row with the new chip_id we will Insert chip_id, status, now()
2. If we have a row with the chip_id AND new status is NOT the same as In the Latest (MOD_STATUS_DATE_TIME) we will Insert chip_id, status, now()
3. If we have a row with the chip_id AND new status is the same as In the Latest (MOD_STATUS_DATE_TIME) we will skip and do nothing.

Could we do this with the MySQL query? Thanks!

I did the same with two separate queries and some code but it would be perfect if I could do it with MySQL only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql Table Insert if not exist otherwise update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update)

Comment: @FahimParkar OP needs in rejecting the insertion, not in existing row update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use trigger. Insert data with `INSERT IGNORE`.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  chip_id INT,
  status CHAR(1),
  mod_status_date_time DATETIME
  );
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1,      123,    'w',    '2024-02-07 11:20:06'),
(2,      456,    'i',    '2024-02-07 11:21:00');
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_test
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.status = ( SELECT status 
                      FROM test 
                      WHERE chip_id = NEW.chip_id 
                      ORDER BY mod_status_date_time DESC LIMIT 1
                      ) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Last ''status'' for this ''chip_id'' is the same, insertion rejected.',
                MYSQL_ERRNO = 1062;
    ELSE
        SET NEW.mod_status_date_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END IF;
END
```

```
-- If we have no row with the new chip_id 
-- we will Insert chip_id, status, now()
INSERT IGNORE INTO test VALUES
(3,      789,    'w',    '2024-02-07 12:20:06');
```

```
-- If we have a row with the chip_id AND new status 
-- is NOT the same as In the Latest (MOD_STATUS_DATE_TIME) 
-- we will Insert chip_id, status, now()
INSERT IGNORE INTO test VALUES
(4,      123,    'x',    '2024-02-07 13:20:06');
```

```
-- If we have a row with the chip_id AND new status
-- is the same as In the Latest (MOD_STATUS_DATE_TIME)
-- we will skip and do nothing
INSERT IGNORE INTO test VALUES
(5,      123,    'x',    '2024-02-07 14:20:06');
```

> ```
> Last 'status' for this 'chip_id' is the same, insertion rejected.
> ```

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

| Level | Code | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Error | 1062 | Last 'status' for this 'chip_id' is the same, insertion rejected. |

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | chip_id | status | mod_status_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | w | 2024-02-07 11:20:06 |
| 2 | 456 | i | 2024-02-07 11:21:00 |
| 3 | 789 | w | 2024-02-07 13:38:51 |
| 4 | 123 | x | 2024-02-07 13:38:51 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Uot1THqt)