# Store multiple email addresses in database for different user types

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Quick question about the most efficient was to handle this, I have a database which has a tree structure of user types,

```
system ---  1 to m --- account --- 1 to m --- customer
```

All three types can have multiple email addresses, I was wondering what would be the best way to handle this in a database, all user types have auto_id as their primary key so having a table with address identified by there related primary key wont work as there will be potentially 3 of each. e.g. email with key 2 , will link to system with id 2 , account with id 2 , etc.

Should I create a table of email addresses for each type .? Or is there a more elegant solution .?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have an email table that has a foreign key which is either a system_id, account_id, or customer_id. Then you can have a field specifying the type of that foreign key. Another more complicated strategy would be to have still the email table but no foreign key. Another table which you would call email_relation consisting of the email_id and the foreign key. That way you could use one e-mail address for all three tables.

Example of the use of two tables

```
system
--------
s1 
s2
s3

account
--------
a1
a2
a3

customer
--------
c1
c2
c3

email
------
e1 example1@a.com
e2 example2@a.com
e3 example3@a.com
e4 example4@a.com

email_relation
---------------
email_id     foreign_id      relation_type
e1           s1              system
e1           a1              account
e1           c1              customer
e2           c1              customer
e3           c2              customer
e4           a3              account
e4           c3              customer
```

if you want the customer table including the e-mail address

```
select c.customer_id, e.email
from customer c
left join email_relation r on (r.foreign_id = c.customer_id and relation_type = 'customer')
left join email          e on (e.email_id    = r.email_id)
where r.email_id is not null
```

If you want all e-mail to a system you could also

```
select e.email
  from email e
  join email_relation r on (r.email_id = e.email_id and relation_type = "system")
 where r.foreign_id = 1
```

Comment: Ok I like this soloution, I have been looking at creating the compost key option and I have across this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/5836504/1401319 which indicates that maybe I would keep the ids in separate columns as suggested, this is good except how would I go about selecting the email for a particular system,

Comment: Do I just use a place holder value in the account and customer columns e.g. "SELECT * FROM email WHERE system = 1 AND account = 0 AND customer = 0" to return the systems email details...Hope this makes sense ..?

Comment: Too many characters messes with my post, what I'm looking for is a solution to the fact that "SELECT * FROM email WHERE system = 1" will return all emails related to sys1 instead of the email for sys1.

Comment: Edited the answer, have a look at the last select statement

Comment: +1 this is a good way to handle this. Balances normalization with readability. Have an extra many to many table would be more complicated than necessary in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a **composite key** to identify a record at any level of the hierarchy, then use it as a FK in your email table. So one email record could point to `sys1.acc7`, some others could point to `sys3.acc4.cus99`. The composite key is made up of auto_ids strung together in whatever way makes sense for your system.

You can determine this composite key for any point in the hierarchy, and from there find all the corresponding email addresses for that point.