# MySQL Insert (conditional) unique value once per user

Tags: mysql, insert, key, unique

I wasn't sure how to explain this in the title, but what I have is a table like this:

```
user_id           | subscription_id
6                   12
6                   10
12                  6
4                   12
```

Each user can subscribe to all other users, but is it possible to prevent a user from subscribing to another user twice through a INSERT query?

As my subscription_id is not unique, this happens:

```
user_id           | subscription_id
6                   12
6                   12
```

And I want to avoid that. As far as I know INSERT IGNORE, INSERT UPDATE and ON DUPLICATE only works with unique keys.

Comment: They work on unique and primary keys actually; not sure about triggers. Bottom line, spanning primary key :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your database table to have a composite primary key for user_id AND subscription_id

That way each row has to be unique across both the columns.

See: [How to properly create composite primary keys - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql)

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it would be that easy! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable and easy way to make sure that a tuple cannot occur more than once inside a single table is either:

1. Use a spanning unique key
2. Use a spanning primary key
3. Maybe triggers

The first two are roughly the same, but unique keys treat null values as distinct as well, so that might not work for you.

```
ALTER TABLE user_subscriptions ADD PRIMARY(user_id, subscription_id);
```