# how to create a composite key in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, composite-key, composite-primary-key

i am working on mysql server.where i have created a table, named question . column/attributes of this table are (course,subject,year,question)
i want to create a primary key(or composite key) consists of (course+subject+year). i.e. for a particular course+subject+year combination there can be only one question.there will be only one row with the combination of (course+subject+year),creation of another row won't be possible.
i have done it by :

```
primary key(course,subject,year);
```

but it's not working.still i can create two rows with same combination of course,subject,year.

can anyone tell me how can i create a composite key propery????

Comment: MySQL server or SQL server? -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql

Comment: When you say not working, define what you mean. Does it throw any errors?

Comment: @oliver for better analysis report....still i can create two with same set of values of(course+subject+year)

Comment: @ChrisCooney...no..still i can create two rows with same combination of course,subject,year

Comment: Okay.. And can you post the rest of the SQL statement?

Comment: rest means???..the insertion command or the create table command??

Comment: Post the whole `CREATE TABLE` statement, and some sample statements that you say created duplicate rows.

Comment: Can you post the whole CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this at sqlfiddle, I got the error `Schema Creation Failed: Duplicate entry 'English-Composition-101' for key 'PRIMARY': `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the syntax is **`CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY(col1,col2,col3)`** for example ::

`CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id,LastName)`

the above example will work if you are writting it while you are creating the table for example ::

```
CREATE TABLE person (
   P_Id int ,
   ............,
   ............,
   CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id,LastName)
);
```

to add this constraint to an existing table you need to follow the following syntax

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (P_Id,LastName)
```

Answer (score 4):

if it is mysql you are looking at, you should do something similar to

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c);
```

Comment: i have set a primary key same way u have written above while creating the table.but it's still allowing 2 or more rows with same combination of a,b,c

Comment: same combo in same order? ie a=1, b=2, c=3 on more than 1 row?

Comment: run SHOW INDEXS table_name and/or SHOW KEYS and see if the key  actually set