# Use an underscore _ as primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I wanted to have a primary key in the form of 1_5_4
where

1 is user id

5 is comp id

4 is round id

Could anyone tell me if this is good/bad practice for MySQL p key design and how it would affect indexing etc.. I know you are meant to keep the p key short but I'm willing to sacrifice this for simplicity of the db design.

Thanks,

Comment: very bad design. normalize your table always. It's a table that colntains 3 columns: `userID`, `compID`, `roundID`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a more confusing db design. I would reccommend the following:

```
user_id
comp_id
round_id
```

as separate fields. You can then configure a composite primary key to cover all 3 fields ensuring uniqueness accross all 3

This question may be useful.
[How to properly create composite primary keys - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql)