# Page view table: I only want one row per ip per page, but can only have one primary key. How do I get around this?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page views table where every time a page is viewed, the user's ip and page id are put in a table. In this table, I only want one row for each ip/page id combination. If I set primary key to ip, then each ip can only be associated with one page. If I set primary key to page id, then only one ip will be associated with each page.

I need both of these to be keys because it's the combination of ip and page id that can not be repeated in the table. How can I do this?

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO page_views (ip, page_id, view_key) VALUES ('$ip', '$page_id', '$view_key') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_key='$view_key'");
```

This is how I need the setup to work - so every time someone views the page, they are assigned a view_key, and it is put in the table. If there is already a record of that ip viewing that page, then the view_key field should be overwritten.

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need compound primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE(...,
PRIMARY KEY(page_id, ip));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you would be:

INSERT INTO **your table** (**user_ip, page_id**)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT **inserted_user_ip, inserted_page_id**) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT **user_ip, page_id** FROM **your table** WHERE **user_id = inserted_user_id AND page_id = inserted_page_id**
) LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

add a unique key to the table

```
ALTER TABLE table_name add unique key(ip_address,page_id);
```