# How to customize data to be inserted?

Tags: mysql

I have this table for items and while inserting it, an ID field(aside from the index id used) should generate a combination of date and autoincrement value in this pattern

"yy-mm-xxx" where yy-last 2 digits of current year, mm-month, xxx-the autogenerated id.

Comment: you have to create this pattern manually, I think MySQL will not do this for you. Also, if ID is auto generated, leave it, create another column and work on it based on ID...

Comment: Generally speaking, this is ill-advised. It's usually harder for software at layers above the database to pull columns apart than it is for the software to put them together. It sounds like what you want is a [composite primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql) (primary key with 2 columns), although an auto-increment ID would be sufficient for uniqueness.

Comment: Is xxx part unique for each `yy-mmm`?

Comment: basically, the xxx part will have to start to 1. (13-07-001) then will reset to 1 once the year changes

Comment: @user2655077 See updated answer. I changed the second example to accommodate for reseting auto-generated part of your id each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you probably better off to store this id in separate columns and present it as needed (e.g. with a view) your words *...autoincrement value...* maybe interpreted at least in two ways:

1. you have an `auto_increment` PK column `id` and you want to use its values while producing this compound secondary id
2. you have a PK column `id` (whether it's `auto_increment` or not) but you want to generate int values that are unique per combination of year and month.

---

**If it's the first case** you can solve this using a separate table for sequencing and a trigger like this

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE items_seq (id int not null auto_increment primary key);
CREATE TABLE items (id int not null default 0 primary key, 
                    item_id varchar(9) default '', ...);
```

A trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_items
BEFORE INSERT ON items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO items_seq (id) VALUES(NULL);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID(),
      NEW.item_id = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y-%m-'),
                           LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you just insert rows

```
INSERT INTO items (item_id) VALUES (NULL),(NULL);
```

And you'll get

```
| ID |   ITEM_ID |
------------------
|  1 | 13-08-001 |
|  2 | 13-08-002 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de6ca/1)** demo

---

**If its the second case** then you can do it with a trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_items
BEFORE INSERT ON items
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.item_id = CONCAT(
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y-%m-'),
    LPAD(COALESCE(
      (
        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(item_id), '-', -1)
          FROM items
         WHERE item_id LIKE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y-%') -- based on your comments reset to 1 every year
      ), 0) + 1, 3, '0'));
```

With this approach you have to issue separate insert statements for each row, otherwise you end up with the same generated number.

```
INSERT INTO items (item_id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO items (item_id) VALUES (NULL);
```

You'll get

```
| ID |   ITEM_ID |
------------------
|  1 | 13-08-001 |
|  2 | 13-08-002 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbeb0/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to have a separate column that would be updated by a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_table_name
  BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.id = <your_own_function_to_create_this_prefixed_id>;
```

Comment: I don't think the `AUTO_INCREMENT` assigned value is available in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. (I seem to recall this, I could be mistaken.)

Comment: You are right... the AUTO_ICREMENT cannot be used as part of the function to update this, did not think of that part of the question

Comment: The logic can be used, without relying on THE id, it can go with some other unique number

Answer (score 0):

Create an `after insert trigger` which should do an update the column based on the pattern you are making

Comment: just to clarify my understanding what is the issue with using before insert

Comment: after insert only we will get the latest auto_increment_id

Comment: In MySql you can't change neither values of a row being inserted in an `AFTER` trigger nor values of any row in a table a trigger is created on. It can only be a `BEFORE` trigger

Comment: That trigger updates a different table Praveen, not sure if I am missing something here

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be accomplished with a trigger, either a BEFORE INSERT or AFTER INSERT. And the value assigned to the AUTO_INCREMENT column isn't available to expressions in the INSERT statement.

About the closest you are going to get (I think) is a separate UPDATE statement. The trick will be identifying the row(s) just inserted. One way would be to insert a NULL value to that column, and then update all rows that have a NULL in that column:

```
UPDATE mytable t 
   SET t.myidcol = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y-%i-'),t.id)
 WHERE t.myidcol IS NULL;
```

(You didn't specify where that date value was coming from; the statement above uses the current date from the system. If it's a date column in the table, then use that instead. The DATE_FORMAT function converts a date/datetime/timestamp into a character string, based on the format supplied in the second argument.

---

**EDIT**

I may have read more into the "(**aside from the index id used**)" and "**autoincrement**" than was intended. I took this to mean that the table has an ID column defined as AUTO_INCREMENT. If that's not the case, then the answer above doesn't really work.

(This is where more details in the question i.e. the output from SHOW CREATE TABLE, and some example data, showing the types of values that would be assigned (whether the autoincrement id is "reset" for each distinct value 'yy-mm-', or whether its continuously ascending.)

If the value of the **autoincrement** portion is derived from a mechanism other than AUTO_INCREMENT, then the assignment of the value to the column could probably be done in a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

---

With all that said, I question the need to store a column in this format. (There is no apparent requirement is being met by the addition of this column, no reason given why this column is needed.)

If the `date` and `id` are stored as separate columns in the table, the generation of the formatted string is trivial, and could be handled in the SELECT list of a query. I can't see that this would be very useful for ordering, given that ordering on the string value is not guaranteed to sort the id values within a given yy-mm- in numerical order, without splitting it back out.

Comment: how about inserting null values first, adding the real values with an update and then using an BEFORE UPDATE trigger

Comment: @skv: if the date value is being stored separately in the table, then yes, that is a workable approach.