# sql string field contain an id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have in my database a table `projects`. 
In this table there is a row `categories` where are all the categories_id where a a project is in. For example a project is in category 1 and 2, so the row value is `1,2`. 
What I want is to count all the projects in a category. So I try this:

```
select * from `projects` WHERE '{$id_cat}' IN (`categories`)
```

but it does not count the projects that have more than one category. I dont want to use `LIKE`

```
select * from `projects` WHERE `categories` LIKE '%{$id_cat}%'
```

because for example if I have a project that is in category 11 and I try to find all project in category 1 this query will return this value too.

Comment: Why you don't want to use like?

Comment: It would be better to have a project / category lookup table. Storing multiple int ID's in a string field like this will only continue to cause you problems.

Comment: did you research **find_in_set**?

Comment: @Kuzgun because if I want projects in  category `1` if I use `like` it will return the projects from multiple categories. For exampla category `11` or `21` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this with `find_in_set()`.  First, though, you can make the `like` work by adding delimiters on both sides:

```
select *
from `projects`
WHERE concat(',', `categories`, ',') LIKE '%,{$id_cat},%';
```

The equivalent `find_in_set()` is:

```
select *
from `projects`
WHERE find_in_set($id_cat, categories) > 0;
```

Comment: Finally I use `like` . I avoided to use it at first because the lack of comma at the beginning and end, but your idea is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you re-structure your database as storing int ID's for foreign keys in a concatenated string will continue to cause you problems.

For example, assuming your database structure is like this (I've not done MySQL for a while so feel free to correct my syntax here):

```
Table: Project
--------------
ID   - INT (PK)
Name -  VARCHAR

Table: Category
---------------
ID   - INT (PK)
Name -  VARCHAR
```

You would have a join table structured like this:

```
Table: ProjectCategoryLookup
----------------------------
CategoryID - INT (FK to Category.ID)
ProjectID - INT (FK to Project.ID)
```

You could then return projects on a category ID by

```
SELECT * FROM Projects P
INNER JOIN ProjectCategoryLookUp LKP ON P.ID = LKP.ProjectID
WHERE LKP.CategoryID IN (11, 12)
```

Ideally, you'd make CategoryID and ProjectID the [compound primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) for the ProjectCategoryLookup, as seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5835978/543538).

Comment: I totally agree with you, but unfortunately I can not modify the datebase, I just have to do some statistics without changing anything in the structure. Thank for the answer, anyway.