# Simple database logic

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to set my logic for a small application. Does this seem ok for the database. I want that every department to have only one manager (function from employee can be simple/manager). if i did separate tables for managers and simple i probably had to do this for users too, right ?

```
EMPLOYEES #id_emp,function,name_emp,adress_emp,salary_emp,@id_dep
USERS,#username,@id_emp,password
DEPARTAMENTS,#id_dep,@id_manager,dep_name

# - primary key
@ - foreign key
```

Comment: I would think that if the only difference between a manager and a non-manager is the value of the one column, then leave them in the same table and make sure your business logic only allows one manager per department

Comment: With this design, you can have a employee without a corresponding user record. It may be better the invert the FK between USERS and EMPLOYEES such that an employee is guaranteed to have a user record (FK from EMPLOYEES to USERS)

Comment: Create complex primary key in DEPARTMENTS with id_dep and id_manager (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql)

Comment: i use this logic for a small practice website. i think it's ok that an employee exists but he doesn't have an username associated but it wouldn't be ok to have an user account without being an employee

Comment: thank you. that should work

Comment: @dskfdskjgds Your schema looks ok for the given requirements.  Perhaps change the `function` field name to a non-reserved word.

Comment: I would remove the function column. when selecting an employee, you can check if it's id exists in id_manager in departments table to find out if the employee is a manager or a simple employee.

Comment: @starko I disagree, I believe departments are uniquely identified by surrogate key id_dep.  A unique constrain on id_manager may be in order, and that would make it a candidate key as well, but a poor choice for a primary key.

Comment: yes. but i think  that means a little more work for the server to do -> a slower response