# Insert ignore multiple columns data unique

Tags: mysql, sql

Im curious if there is a way to insert into MySQL and avoid duplicates. I know there are three primary ways of accomplishing it. Either Replace, insert ignore or insert on duplicate key. I believe that each of these rely on a unique primary key which for me is a auto increment id field.  This id field does not have any value for my particular inserting needs instead i want to check if a few fields contain the same value if not dont insure

ex:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, team, email) VALUES (:n, :t, :e)
```

if i had three data sets like so

```
1) array (":n" => "john doe", ":t" => 1, ":e" => john@doe.com);
2) array (":n" => "Jane doe", ":t" => 1, ":e" => john@doe.com);
3) array (":n" => "john doe", ":t" => 1, ":e" => john1@doe.com);
4) array (":n" => "john doe", ":t" => 2, ":e" => john1@doe.com);
```

Assuming there are no values in the table

1, 3 and 4 would be inserted but 2 would not as the team and email are not unique

I am aware i could create a fourth column and add the email and team to it and create a unique value and use this however i would prefer not to do so as it is redundant data .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `id` field has no value for you, don't bother with it.  The desired behavior you're describing is that of a [composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql), so make a composite key.

First, scrap the one that exists and is of no value...

`ALTER TABLE YourTableName DROP PRIMARY KEY;`

Then create the new composite one...

`ALTER TABLE YourTableName ADD PRIMARY KEY (name, team, email);`

Comment: composite key - so simple!

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `UNIQUE` constrain

```
 ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD UNIQUE `unique_idx`(`name`, `team`, `email`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DUAL

```
INSERT INTO table (name, team, email)
SELECT :n, :t, :e
FROM DUAL
WHERE :t NOT IN (SELECT team FROM table WHERE email = :e)
```