# How can I delimit the possible values of a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have three tables in a MySQL DB.
This is the main table with organisation related stuff. Every Organisation has an unique identifier which is also the foreign key in some tables.

```
org
+------------+-------------+ 
| org_id     | name        |   
+------------+-------------+ 
| 1          | a           | 
| 2          | b           |  
| 3          | c           |  
+------------+-------------+
```

This is the groups table. Organisations can have many groups.

```
groups
FOREIGN KEY (ORG_ID) REFERENCES ORG (ID);
+------------+-------------+----------+ 
| ID         | org_id      |   name   |
+------------+-------------+ ---------+
| 1          | 1           |  Group1  |
| 2          | 2           |  Group2  |
| 3          | 2           |  Group3  |
+------------+-------------+----------+
```

And this is the feed table in which I would like to perform an update.
A feed can have only one associated group.

```
feed
FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_ID) REFERENCES GROUPS (ID);
+------------+-------------+--------------+ 
| ID         | org_id      |   group_id   |
+------------+-------------+ -------------+
| 1          | 1           |      1       |
| 2          | 2           |      2       |
| 3          | 1           |     NULL     |
| 4          | 2           |      3       |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

So now there is one problem, that i can't solve. When I `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a row, I set the `groups_id`, but this can also be a `groups_id` which not belongs to the organisation.
This happens, because all ID's in GROUPS are valid FK values. That's a thing I want to avoid. It should only be possible to `insert` or `update` a row with a `groups_id` which has also the same `org_id` as in `feeds.org_id`.

As you can see, the data is now fine. But when I try to make this `INSERT INTO feed VALUES (4, 2, 1)` it were nice to see an error. Yeah, right, I'm missing an lovely error....

It is difficult for me to make an connection between them. There seems one information or method that I'm missing. I've been looking for a lot, but I don't know the words to describe my problem.

So I ask you, could you give me a tip?

EDIT:

All feeds and all groups are related to an organisation, which has an identifier. An organisation can create feeds/messages. When this feeds are not associated with a group, this feed ist public. For special feeds they can create a group. This group is related to this special organisation.

This works and everything is good:

```
UPDATE feed 
SET title = "Title", message = "Message", groups_id = "1" 
WHERE id = "1" AND org_id = "1"
```

But this works also:

```
UPDATE feed 
SET title = "Title", message = "Message", groups_id = "2" 
WHERE id = "1" AND org_id = "1"
```

The problem is, that it is possible to associate a group to a feed (which is associated to org 1), while the group is not associated with the org (group 2 is associated with org 2).

So my thought was, is there a way to solve this through FOREIGN KEY or similar (checks, joins, subqueries). Or should I think about my db design?

Comment: Your mistake is including `org_id` in `feed` in the first place. It should be derived through the `groups` table by the `group_id`.

Comment: why does org able need an id and org_id both?

Comment: @shmosel The thing is, I need the org_id in FEED to associate the feeds, where is no groups_id given. All rows who are not linked to an group, are NULL and automatically in the public group. But only to the given org_id.

Comment: You're saying not all feeds have a group, but they all have an org? Interesting. Would it be feasible to define a separate public group for each org?

Comment: @e4c5 this is a simpler illustration. org table is normally the user table and  a organisation can have many user. thought it would be so easyer

Comment: I think you need to post an MCVE  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @e4c5 you're right. I will try to provide a better explanation.

Comment: Please could you specify clearly the relationships that you intend to model?  So, you have three entity types; org, group, and feed.  From what I can see, each Group can only belong to one Org, but an Org can have many Groups or even no Groups.  The way I represent that is `Orgs(1) : (0..many)Groups`  *(An Org can have 0 to many associated Groups, a Group can and must have 1 associated Org)*  Then, I believe you also have `Groups(1) : (0..many)Feeds`?  In which case your `feeds` table doesn't need the `org_id` field, just the `group_id` field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a composed foreign key solves your problem:

```sql
create table agroup (
  id int primary key,
  orgid int,
  UNIQUE (id,orgid)
);

create table feed (
  id int primary key,
  groupid int,
  orgid int,
  FOREIGN KEY (groupid, orgid) REFERENCES agroup(id, orgid)
);

insert into agroup values (10, 1), (20, 1), (30, 2), (40, NULL);
insert into feed values (100,10,1), (101, 20, 1);
insert into feed values (102, 40, NULL); # works
insert into feed values (103, NULL, 1); # works as well
# insert into feed values (110,10,2); # yields error "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"
```

Note the `UNIQUE(id,orgid)`, which seems to be necessary. Though I do not understand why `agroup(id primary key)` is not sufficient to make also `agroup(id,orgid)` unique, I got a compiler error without this explicit `unique(id,orgid`)-constraint. Documentation says that the referenced attributes must be indexed. Anyway, your problem should be solved.

EDIT: Extended example, which now demonstrates also the case of NULL-values in referencing attributes.

At least in MySQL, a composite foreign key constraint permits NULL values in the referencing (child) rows, regardless of whether the parent table contain rows with corresponding NULL-values or not. If one inserts a row with NULL-values for foreign-key attributes, the foreign key constraint is simply ignored. Confer [mysql foreign key semantics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), which says:
"... MySQL essentially implements the semantics defined by MATCH SIMPLE, which permit a foreign key to be all or partially NULL. In that case, the (child table) row containing such a foreign key is permitted to be inserted, and does not match any row in the referenced (parent) table. It is possible to implement other semantics using triggers."

Comment: damn it didn't occur to me that the foreign key can  be composed like this because the org_id obviously references the other table, yes so this is right!

Comment: There is the corner case of 'public' feeds which have no group *(group_id)* IS NULL.  But that would break your foreign key constraint.  Instead, there should be an explicit group for each organisation called 'public', so as to no longer need NULL values

Comment: I will test this tomorrow intensely, but it seems to solve my problem. thank you a lot! @MatBailie I thought, I could save up an entry. I will rework my shema. thx.

Comment: FYI: You also can create a composite [**primary key**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql)

Comment: I've tested it, it works perfect! This is exactly the behavior I wanted. That I can use NULL values furthermore is awesome. So I dont have to setup an extra group, that isn't actually needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want to avoid NULL values, simply make the respective columns "NOT NULL", e.g. feed(..., groupid int not null, ...)