# Please Tell me if i am making any mistake while designing this database Using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

my basic requirement is I have some languages in the languages table. then I am adding my words and their translations in different languages. So to store that data I hope I am right the situation is one-to-many relationships.
please have a look at the image.
[image]

am I using a correct design? Or it could be better than this? any suggestions?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: @james. Thanks for the reply)

Comment: What do you plan on storing in the words.word field? Is that where the original term (English, I presume) is to be stored?

Comment: @chabzjo yes. Word will be in English.

Comment: Actually, a "word:" will be related to a single language, so a language id should be in the word table. Then a table that links that word to it's equivalent in another language, called "translations". It would have two keys pointing to the "words" table.

Answer (score 1):

The following tables could be used:

- language

  - id (key)
  - short text
- term

  - language id (key)
  - id (key)
  - text
- translation

  - language_id1 (key)
  - term_id1 (key)
  - language_id2 (key)
  - term_id2 (key)

Comment: Is it really better solution?

Comment: @rakeshkohali no

Comment: @Strawberry  please explain me how I can make this better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion. *I normally prepend my IDs by the table name to make it easier to read. Obviously, you can use the naming standards you prefer.*

```
Language
- LanguageID
- Description

Term
- TermID

Translation
- LanguageID
- TermID
- Text
```

As for the key for the Translation table, it depends on how many translations you will allow per language.

If you allow multiple, then add a TranslationID.

If you want to force just one, use a concatenated key of LanguageID and TermID. See [How to properly create composite primary keys - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql)

I know it looks odd to have a table with just a key in it, but this structure has multiple advantages.

- It will allow you to query only one field when doing a search, regardless of whether you're translating FROM English or TO English.
- If one day, you need to translate between languages other than English, you're already set.
- You can translate the same word more than once, depending on its different meanings.

Here is an example of how to use it

```
Language
1 English
2 French
3 Spanish

Term
1

Translation
1 1 Dog
1 1 Hound  -- (if this is allowed, add a TranslationID)
2 1 Chien
3 1 Perro
```

Comment: Every translation a -> b is indicates also a  translation b -> a. So why would you want translation texts in a different table than source texts?

Comment: @Xypron: The translation texts are all in the Translation table, just like for your suggestion.