# Storing post likes of each user in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am planning to have likes plugin in my website where: I have 18000+ of contents to display and 380+ users (more in future).

I thought to have the database table for the same as:

```
 ___________________
| User_Id | Post_Id |
|___________________|
|   15    |   288   |
|   185   |  14358  |
|   185   |   3855  |
|_________|_________|
```

If I store the values in the database, the database will have huge content and huge **traffic** and will **need large storage** too. (**6840K** values only for now then imagine the stage of values after 2 years.)

Any other best alternatives?

Comment: This actually seems like the tidiest solution already if you need to know which user's liked which posts (otherwise you could use an aggregate *number of likes per post*). If by *large storage* you mean space taken on the disk - I'm betting it'll be far smaller than that taken by the *posts* data. If you're worried about the number of records - well, they're really simple records, just make a compound primary key on `User_Id` and `Post_Id` and it should be fine.

Comment: The real "data" will be less, since not every user on your platform will like every post.

Comment: @CD001 How to make a compound primary key on `User_Id` and `Post_Id`?

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql) ;)

Comment: storage is cheap. How much data are you anticipating, exactly?