# multiple primary key defined

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a composite key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE authorprofile  
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (a_id, a_firstname);
```

I then tried to add an identifier like so:

```
ALTER TABLE authorprofile  
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_id_firstname PRIMARY KEY (a_id, a_firstname);
```

but i get a "multiple primary key defined error"

Comment: show us please also the create table, i am sure there is already a primary key, and you can only have one, so delet the old one first

Comment: That is a composite primary key. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql

Comment: CREATE TABLE AuthorProfile  
  (  
     a_id        INT NOT NULL,  
     a_firstname CHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
     a_lastname  CHAR(50),  
     a_booktitle VARCHAR(50),  
     a_genre     VARCHAR(10),  
     isbn        VARCHAR(20)  
  );
  ALTER TABLE authorprofile  
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (a_id, a_firstname);  
that is the create tale block