# Joining a table of properties as columns and values?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

```
CREATE TABLE person_properties (
  person_id INT,  
  key TEXT,
  value TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id, key)
);

CREATE TABLE persons (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

I've done this:

```
INSERT INTO persons DEFAULT_VALUES;  -- suppose id is 1
INSERT INTO person_properties (person_id, key, value) VALUES (1, 'age', '30')
INSERT INTO person_properties (person_id, key, value) VALUES (1, 'weight', '20lb')
```

I'd like to select `person`s with `age` and `weight` as columns, with the values from `person_properties` (or `NULL` if it doesn't exist). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM persons
LEFT OUTER JOIN person_properties p1 ON persons.person_id = p1.person_id AND p1.key = 'age'
LEFT OUTER JOIN person_properties p2 ON persons.person_id = p2.person_id AND p2.key = 'weight'
```

Answer (score -1):

Your schema is wrong.

`key` is reserved & you can't have 2 primary keys in a unique table.

```
CREATE TABLE person_properties (
  person_id INT,  
  cle TEXT,
  value TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE persons (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

and

You can't to have twice same primary key ...

```
INSERT INTO person_properties (person_id, cle, value) VALUES (**1**, 'age', '30');
INSERT INTO person_properties (person_id, cle, value) VALUES (**1**, 'weight', '20lb');
```

If you must have 2 lines with the same key, it's not good.

I advice you to redo//rethink your schema.

**EDIT :**

```
CREATE TABLE person_properties (
  person_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  pkey VARCHAR(10),
  value TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id, pkey)
);

CREATE TABLE persons (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO person_properties (pkey, value) VALUES ('age', '30');
INSERT INTO person_properties (pkey, value) VALUES ('weight', '20lb');
```

Comment: You *can* have multiple columns in a primary key. Postgresql see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html,  Mysql see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642778/multi-column-primary-key-in-mysql-5

Comment: These are the same enitity, not the same key. It's fine, just difficult to work with. (key IS a reserved word though!)

Comment: @harmic : Yes but he can NOT use key/cle as primary key !!! His type is TEXT and a primary key HAS TO have a fixed length. And his INSERT INTO queries are though false...

Comment: If you mean it is not a good design, well sure that is arguable. Using EAV is rarely a good idea. But there is no reason why a primary key cannot have a TEXT column as part of it. OPs schema does work - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7330e/1/0

Comment: I misread... Of course it works with PostgreSQL but not with mysql :s