# liquibase : error with malformed foreign key

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have this create statement  :

```
    <addPrimaryKey 
        constraintName="pk_sitetv_consultant"
        columnNames="consultants_id, sitetv_id" 
        tableName="sitetv_consultant"/>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="sitetv_id"
                             baseTableName="sitetv_consultant"
                             constraintName="fk_sitetv_consultant_sitetv_id"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"
                             referencedTableName="site_tv"/>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="consultants_id"
                             baseTableName="sitetv_consultant"
                             constraintName="fk_sitetv_consultant_consultant_id"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"
                             referencedTableName="consultant"/>
```

But when  I run the webapp I am gettin this error :

```
2016-03-24 10:34:31.537 ERROR 7322 --- [lley-Executor-1] c.t.r.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Migration failed for change set classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160324092108_changelog.xml::1458811279836-12::tv (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error on rename of './m/#sql-522_bc' to './myApp/sitetv_consultant' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed) [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE myApp.sitetv_consultant DROP PRIMARY KEY]

liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160324092108_changelog.xml::1458811279836-12::tv (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error on rename of './myApp/#sql-522_bc' to './myApp/sitetv_consultant' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed) [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE myApp.sitetv_consultant DROP PRIMARY KEY]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:590) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:212) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:434) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:391) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.tv.myApp.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.tv.myApp.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error on rename of './myApp/#sql-522_bc' to './myApp/sitetv_consultant' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed) [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE myApp.sitetv_consultant DROP PRIMARY KEY]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:301) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:107) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1251) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1234) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:554) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error on rename of './myApp/#sql-522_bc' to './myApp/sitetv_consultant' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2505) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:840) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:740) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.StatementProxy.execute(StatementProxy.java:94) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.HikariStatementProxy.execute(HikariStatementProxy.java) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:299) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

What is wrong with my xml file?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the way Liquibase is generating multi-column primary keys is incorrect. It appears that MySQL does support multi-column primary keys (see [Multi-Column Primary Key in MySQL 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642778/multi-column-primary-key-in-mysql-5)) but that the SQL genberated is incorrect. You might try running the `updateSQL` command rather than the `update` command to see what SQL is being generated.